# Facebook Sign In SDK XCODE

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sdk, facebook-login

I have implemented Sign In with Apple successfully on my app via Xcode, I have also added Facebook sign in. The problem is they work well when in two different projects, but when I add them together only sign in with Apple shows up and Facebook disappears. Im stumped, any help would be appreciated.
Updated post with relevant code, insight would be appreciated, thanks.

```
import AuthenticationServices
import UIKit
import FacebookLogin
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

private let signInButton = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(signInButton)
    signInButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapSignIn), for: .touchUpInside)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    signInButton.frame = CGRect (x: 50, y: 5, width: 250, height: 50)
    signInButton.center = view.center
 }

@objc func didTapSignIn() {
    let provider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
    let request = provider.createRequest()
    request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
    
    let controller = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
    controller.delegate = self
    controller.presentationContextProvider = self
    controller.performRequests()
}
}

 extension ViewController: ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate   {
func authorizationController(controller:     ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error) {
    print("failed!")
}

func authorizationController(controller:    ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
    switch authorization.credential{
    case let credentials as ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential:
        let firstname = credentials.fullName?.givenName
        let lastname = credentials.fullName?.familyName
        let email = credentials.email
        break
    
    default:
        break
    }
}
}

extension ViewController: ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding {
func presentationAnchor(for controller: ASAuthorizationController) -> ASPresentationAnchor {
    return view.window!





class ViewController: UIViewController, LoginButtonDelegate {


    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if let token = AccessToken.current,!token.isExpired {
            let token = token.tokenString
             
            
        }
        else{
            
            let loginButton = FBLoginButton()
            loginButton.center = view.center
            loginButton.delegate = self
        loginButton.frame = CGRect(x: 76, y: 550, width: 250, height: 50)
            loginButton.permissions = ["public_profile",    "email"]
            view.addSubview(loginButton)

        }
    
    }

func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton, didCompleteWith result: LoginManagerLoginResult?, error: Error?)        {
   
}


func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton) {
    
}

}
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may want to take a look at [ask]. This problem is likely impossible to debug without the relevant code.

Comment: I updated my post check it out